# For react-admin-demo is it compulsory to do complete build of react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

For react-admin-demo is it compulsory to do complete build of react-admin. 
As per documentation it goes through clumsy make process.

Have anybody installed the folder itself by just npm install and run?

Any hints on how that can be simplified, to fork and create my own project?

Reference: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mono repository which includes many packages. It uses learn and yarn workspaces. You'll have to use `yarn`.

There are several scripts inside the main `package.json` file which can help you start contributing without `make`. Each package inside `packages` can be built by running `yarn build` inside its folder.

To build all packages in one command, you can run `./node_modules/.bin/lerna run build` inside the root folder.